# Two NSURLConnections in one View

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I have two NSURLConnections in one View. One for a Collection View and one for a Table View. I have different tables in my database and I get the data via JSON in my App. So I made two asynchronously NSURLConnection and all my picture are downloaded with SDWebImage. So I have two Array with different data. In my App before with one NSURLConnection and one Array all worked perfect. But now I have problems that my TableView doesnt show me the data if it loads the data with cellular network.

I get this message

```
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1f8bed80
```

Why do I get this message? Are two NSURLConnections too much in one View?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with your app. It's a message that is a standard part of iOS 6.0 functioning. Just ignore this message.

See [Technical Q&A QA1774: purgeIdleCellConnections Log Message](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1774/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012992).